# Make blog available to authenticated users only

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I have a site which lists some events in a block using the agenda module.  I have this set to be the main content (eg taking up the center of the page).  This is the only content I would like general visitor to see.

I would like to use the same site to have a private blog which is only available to logged in users.

Is there a  way I can restrict viewing of the blog pages to anyone not logged in?

I have tried simply removing the view content permission but this causes other issues!

Comment: Is the block a view, or it is created by other modules?

Answer (score 1):

Would the 'Content Access' module be what you are looking for?

http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Using this you would be able to set your Blog content type to be viewable only by registered users.